# Modyfing code completion in PhpStorm 5

Tags: phpstorm

After entering first characters of `<textarea>` tag and using autocomplete ( e.g. `<texta` and hitting ENTER) editor generates following snippet: `<textarea rows="" cols=""`

It's extremely unhelpful since I don't use rows and cols attributes.

How can I modify those snippets ?
I tried "Live templates" section but it's not there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case code completion is performed according to the DTD, which defines `rows` and `cols` attributes of the `textarea` tag as **Required**.

Most likely your file starts with:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

or the default HTML language level defines it.

To address this problem you can create HTML 5 files with `<!DOCTYPE html>` and PhpStorm will stop completing these attributes.

See also the related IDE setting:

[image]